# skinned surface

Tags: numerical-methods

In the representation of a skinned surface using $B$-Spline, I have $K+1$ given curves of degree $p$ on a common partition $U$ and I want to construct the surface $S(u,v)$ with these curves as isoparametric curves. Assuming that $p$ is the degree in $u$, and $q$ is the degree in $v$, why should I ask that the degree $q$ must be less than or equal to $K$? I found this condition in my book.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing a skinning surface through given curves is pretty much the same calculation as constructing a curve through given points, so all the same rules apply.

A curve (or a skinned surface) of degree $q$ needs at least $q+1$ interpolation values to fully specify it. So, in the case of a skinning surface, the number of curves ($K+1$) must be at least $q+1$. In other words, $K+1 \ge q+1$, so $q \le K$.

Comment: By the way ... if you want more b-spline questions answered, please upvote or accept the answers you have already been given (or tell us what's wrong with them).